# PowerApps: AddMedia Control - Add more than 1 element?

Tags: powerapps

PowerApps: in the "AddMedia-Control": How can I Add/pick more than 1 element ...?
For excample I want to pick some pictures (example 5-6) from the galerie in one step for a documentation.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment this is not supported. Please consider creating a new feature request in the [PowerApps Ideas board](https://aka.ms/powerapps-ideas) for this scenario.